# Bug Loading Photo in Dispatch Queue

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I have this block of code here which I use to load an image on a dispatch queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    CGImageRef x = self.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [[self imageView] setImage: [UIImage imageWithCGImage: x]];
    });
});
```

The code seems to work a couple of times until eventually I get a bad access at this line `[[self imageView] setImage: [UIImage imageWithCGImage: x]];`. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
CGImageRef x = CGImageCreateCopy(self.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage);
```

and

```
CGImageRelease(x)
```

after you set that

Answer (score 1):

Try releasing the CGImageRef in its own queue rather than passing it to from one asynchronous queue to another:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    CGImageRef x = self.asset.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage;
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: x];
    CGImageRelease(x);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [[self imageView] setImage: img];
    });
});
```

If that simple hack doesn't work, then it's time to fire up Instruments and see what's actually leaking.